# A More Symmetric Distribution?

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, symmetry

**REVISED QUESTION**

I am interested in learning more about why certain confidence intervals are better than others in a logistic regression setting.  Based on some readings and discussions with more experienced colleges, I understand that the most common method to obtain an approximate confidence interval for $\hat{p}$ estimated from a logistic regression model is to find the endpoints of the 95% confidence interval for $\log({\hat{p}\over{1-\hat{p}}})=\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1$ and then take the inverse logit of that.

An alternative method that I thought of was to simply write $\hat{p}$ as $\exp({\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1})\over{1+\exp({\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1})}$.  I could then use the delta method to obtain 95% confidence intervals.  From what I understand, in this case, the Delta method would have reduced coverage probability because $\log({\hat{p}\over{1-\hat{p}}})=\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1$  has a more nearly symmetric distribution than $\exp({\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1})\over{1+\exp({\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1})}$.  Can somehow help me understand this?

How does one know that $\log({\hat{p}\over{1-\hat{p}}})=\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1$ has a more nearly symmetric distribution?  Why does it perform better than the Delta Method?

**OLD QUESTION:**

If I have two functions, say $f(\hat{\beta}_0, \hat{\beta}_1)=\log({\hat{p}\over{1-\hat{p}}})=\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1$ and $f(\beta_0, \beta_1)=\hat{p}$=$\exp({\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1})\over{1+\exp({\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1})}$, is there a way I can tell which one has a more nearly symmetric distribution than the other?

I'm asking this because I was looking into variance estimation (for the purpose of forming large sample, approximate confidence intervals) for $\hat{p}$ from a simple logistic regression model with one binary predictor variable that takes on values 0 and 1.  Most textbooks recommend taking the endpoints of the confidence interval for $\log({\hat{p}\over{1-\hat{p}}})=\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1$ and then using the inverse logit to "get better coverage probability" because it has more nearly of a symmetric distribution than $f(\hat{\beta}_0, \hat{\beta}_1)=\hat{p}$=$\exp({\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1})\over{1+\exp({\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1})}$ (when considering using the delta method with the later).  I don't understand this.  How does one know that the first has better coverage probability?  How do you know it is more nearly symmetric?

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: (The first equation does not clearly define a function.  If you intend it to define $\hat p$ implicitly in terms of $\beta_0+\beta_1$, then it's *identical* to the second formula.)  In what sense do you mean "more symmetric" and why would it matter?  Where does any kind of "distribution" come into play when you are only discussing functions?

Comment: @Analyst1 In logistic regression, the linear predictor is $\nu = \beta_0 + \beta_1$ whereas the fitted value is $\eta = \hat{p} = \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1) / (1+ \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1)$. If they are estimated from a random sample of $(Y_1, X_1), ... (Y_n, X_n)$ observations, the $\nu$ and $\eta$s have some distributional properties... but is that actually what you're asking?

Comment: @whuber, I've revised my question.  Does this help?

Comment: The context helps, but I'm still stuck at the first line: your first expression involving "$f$" does not define a function at all.  The notation and terminology are still confusing.  I believe I can guess what you are going after, but you are leaving a lot of details for the reader to determine, so my guess could differ from someone else's guess.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm not sure of a better way to ask this. I'm not sure what  you mean that the first expression doesn't define a function at all.  I thought this was a function of $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$, no?  Maybe I should just remove the first few lines and ask the question without the mathematics?

Comment: The first expression just defines a constant as the sum of two constants with the usual hat notation. If you want to talk about a sampling distribution, you'll need to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks guys.  @whuber, does the revised question make more sense now?